# How can I implement a dictionary in python that is persistent to disk in a way I can recover from a failure?

Tags: python, dictionary, crash, persistence, pyzmq

I have a producer-consumer implementation that I'm implementing with [pyzmq](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/) (I took the example from [here](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html):
I have one producer that produce simultaneously objects to several different types of consumer, where each type of consumer, process this object in a different way.

In addition, I have a manager/supervisor that gets messages regarding the states of the processed objects (e.g. `sent_from_producer_to_consumer_1`, `processed_by_consumer_2`, etc), that stores, for each object, all of these states in a dictionary that it's key is the object logical ID and it's values is the list of states.

I want to protect my system from total loss of information in case of a system-failure by recovering it to the latest state it has been at.

So my question is - how can I do that? how can I make sure the manager's objects' states is disk persistent?

Comment: 1. use DB; 2. pickle.dump; 3. write to file

Comment: 4. [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package/library called [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) that satisfies my wishes. From the documentation :

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object ...

Answer (score 0):

For a trivial use-case, you can serialize the data to disk using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) or if your objects are really simple, you can even use JSON. Databases are also valid for such tasks and scale better.

Pickle works as follows:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> d = dict(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
>>> with open("/tmp/test.pkl", "wb") as f:
...    pickle.dump(d, f)
...
>>> with open("/tmp/test.pkl", "wb") as f:
...    print(pickle.load(f))
{'bar': 2, 'foo': 1, 'baz': 3}
```

Comment: Not good enough - I need something that will automatically sync the data to the disk for me. I don't want to implement such mechanism that I'm pretty sure exists already

Comment: It just so seems that persistence is left for the user of zmq to deal with. It's not huge task, perhaps 20 lines of code. Catch-all exception where you store the state and reraise the exception. Load atinit.